# woocommerce custom product type - make variations possible

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I know, a lot has already been written about this, but i dont get it to work.
I have a custom product type, "Elearning" and i have registered it, and included a file for the add-to-cart template. This template is a copy of the add-to-cart/variable.php file.
With jquery i made the variations visible in the admin side. So far so good and on the back side, it is working.

However, when a person visits the product on the front end, it doesnt work.
i get the errors

```
notice: undefined variable $attribute_keys
notice: undefined variable $available_variations;
```

As a result, this leads to not being able to display the variations and buy the product.

$attribute_keys however, can easily be set:

```
$attribute_keys  = $product->get_attributes();
```

However, i am struggling with $available_variations.
the function get_available_variations() does not work on not-variable products.

Any idea how to solve this problem?

Comment: Well, your question does not contain [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) 
but the bottom line is that if you create a custom product you have to take over the functions you want to use. You can easily find out how you can do this by looking at how WooCommerce already applies this for variable products

Comment: Hi, yes i agree it is minimal code, but it can be quite lengthy... Its standard registering a custom product type, adding a file to the add-to-cart folder with the correct name etc. Nothing really noticeble. But i have a hard time figuring out how to get $available_variations working for Elearning product type. I looked at the core file, but the code is dependent on other functions and i think the problem is somewhere it is checked wether a product is variable or not...

Comment: I understand, i would say, minimize your existing code to the essential parts and put that code in your question. A hint: what I sometimes do is look at the source code of existing plugins (which actually do what I'm looking for) and how this is applied there and then more or less copy that code. It is not always necessary to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: @7uc1f3r You have been right, my bet... It was enough to simply extend the WC_Product_Variable instead of the WC_Product... Then nothing is really needed and a case of simply copying the variable product add to cart template file and renaming it to the custom product type. Thanks for your input anyways!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, apparently i overlooked a major simple solution.
The most easy way is to extend the WC_Product_Variable class instead of the standard WC_Product class.

So I changed:

```
function register_elearning_type () {

    class WC_Product_Elearning extends WC_Product {

        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'Elearning';
            parent::__construct( $product );
            }
        }
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'register_elearning_type' );
```

To this:

```
function register_elearning_type () {

    class WC_Product_Elearning extends WC_Product_Variable {

        public function __construct( $product ) {
            $this->product_type = 'Elearning';
            parent::__construct( $product );
            }
        }
}

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'register_elearning_type' );
```

And then everything works like a charm.